# Vuforia related errors occur during unity building

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens

我的unity版本為2020.3.43版，vuforia engine版本為10.18.4版，MRTK版本為2.8.2.0
在unity3D的MixedRealityToolkit裡將main camera附加vuforia behaviour，執行後可以偵測到圖片並顯示，再將unity建置卻出現以下兩樣錯誤要如何解決?
1.
Reference Rewriter found some errors while running with command "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.SpatialTracking.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.XR.LegacyInputHelpers.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.InputSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\netstandard.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Tools.Runtime.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.TeleportSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.SpatialAwarenessSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.SceneSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.InputSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.InputSimulation.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.InputAnimation.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.DiagnosticsSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Services.CameraSystem.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.Subsystem.Registration.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SDK.Experimental.Interactive.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.XRSDK.WindowsMixedReality.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.XRSDK.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsVoiceInput.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsSceneUnderstanding.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.WindowsMixedReality.Shared.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Providers.OpenXR.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Gltf.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Async.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.OpenXR.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.GraphicsTools.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SDK.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.TextMeshPro.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.ARFoundation.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.Timeline.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.WindowsMixedReality.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.OpenXR.Features.RuntimeDebugger.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.OpenXR.Features.OculusQuestSupport.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.OpenXR.Features.MockRuntime.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.OpenXR.Features.MetaQuestSupport.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.OpenXR.Features.ConformanceAutomation.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.OpenXR.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.Management.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.InteractionSubsystems.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.CoreUtils.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Unity.XR.ARSubsystems.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\VuforiaScripts.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Vuforia.Unity.Engine.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\nunit.framework.dll" "--target=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Vuforia.Unity.Wrapper.dll" "--additionalreferences=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\x64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\X64,Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Plugins\ARM64" "--platform=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.18362.0\Facade\Windows.winmd" "--dbg=pdb" "--framework=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed" "--alt=Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles,mscorlib;System,mscorlib;System,System;System,System.ComponentModel.Composition;System,System.Core;System.CodeDom.Compiler,System;System.Collections,mscorlib;System.Collections.Concurrent,mscorlib;System.Collections.Concurrent,System;System.Collections.Generic,mscorlib;System.Collections.Generic,System;System.Collections.Generic,System.Core;System.Collections.ObjectModel,mscorlib;System.Collections.ObjectModel,System;System.Collections.Specialized,System;System.ComponentModel,System;System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema,System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;System.Data,System.Data;System.Data.Common,System.Data;System.Diagnostics,mscorlib;System.Diagnostics,System;System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis,mscorlib;System.Diagnostics.Contracts,mscorlib;System.Diagnostics.Tracing,mscorlib;System.Dynamic,System.Core;System.Globalization,mscorlib;System.IO,mscorlib;System.IO,System;System.IO,System.Core;System.IO,System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml;System.IO.Compression,System;System.IO.Compression,System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;System.IO.IsolatedStorage,mscorlib;System.Linq,System.Core;System.Linq.Expressions,System.Core;System.Net,System;System.Net.NetworkInformation,System;System.Net.Security,System;System.Net.Sockets,System;System.Numerics,System.Numerics;System.Reflection,mscorlib;System.Reflection.Emit,mscorlib;System.Resources,mscorlib;System.Runtime,mscorlib;System.Runtime.CompilerServices,mscorlib;System.Runtime.CompilerServices,System.Core;System.Runtime.ExceptionServices,mscorlib;System.Runtime.InteropServices,mscorlib;System.Runtime.InteropServices,System;System.Runtime.InteropServices,System.Core;System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes,mscorlib;System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes,System;System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime,mscorlib;System.Runtime.Serialization,mscorlib;System.Runtime.Serialization,System.Runtime.Serialization;System.Runtime.Serialization.Json,System.Runtime.Serialization;System.Runtime.Versioning,mscorlib;System.Runtime.Versioning,System;System.Security,mscorlib;System.Security.Authentication,System;System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection,System;System.Security.Claims,mscorlib;System.Security.Principal,mscorlib;System.ServiceModel,System.ServiceModel;System.ServiceModel.Channels,System.ServiceModel;System.ServiceModel.Description,System.ServiceModel;System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher,System.ServiceModel;System.ServiceModel.Security,System.ServiceModel;System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens,System.ServiceModel;System.Text,mscorlib;System.Text.RegularExpressions,System;System.Threading,mscorlib;System.Threading,System;System.Threading,System.Core;System.Threading.Tasks,mscorlib;System.Threading.Tasks,System.Core;System.Windows.Input,System;System.Xml,System.Runtime.Serialization;System.Xml,System.Xml;System.Xml.Linq,System.Xml.Linq;System.Xml.Schema,System.Xml;System.Xml.Serialization,System.Xml;,Windows.winmd;,Windows.AI.MachineLearning.MachineLearningContract.winmd;,Windows.AI.MachineLearning.Preview.MachineLearningPreviewContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.CallsBackgroundContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsPhoneContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.CommunicationBlocking.CommunicationBlockingContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract.winmd;,Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd;,Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd;,Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract.winmd;,Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract.winmd;,Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.winmd;,Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd;,Windows.Services.Maps.GuidanceContract.winmd;,Windows.Services.Maps.LocalSearchContract.winmd;,Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd;,Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract.winmd;,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract.winmd;,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract.winmd;,Windows.System.Profile.SystemManufacturers.SystemManufacturersContract.winmd;,Windows.System.SystemManagementContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.Xaml.Core.Direct.XamlDirectContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationCameraSettingsContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ContactActivatedEventsContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebUISearchActivatedEventsContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundAlarmApplicationContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.LockScreenCallContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.InkWorkspace.PreviewInkWorkspaceContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Preview.Notes.PreviewNotesContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Management.ResourceIndexerContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.Core.SearchCoreContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchContract.winmd;,Windows.ApplicationModel.Wallet.WalletContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.Portable.PortableDeviceContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.Printers.Extensions.ExtensionsContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.Scanners.ScannerDeviceContract.winmd;,Windows.Devices.Sms.LegacySmsApiContract.winmd;,Windows.Gaming.Input.GamingInputPreviewContract.winmd;,Windows.Gaming.Preview.GamesEnumerationContract.winmd;,Windows.Gaming.UI.GameChatOverlayContract.winmd;,Windows.Gaming.UI.GamingUIProviderContract.winmd;,Windows.Globalization.GlobalizationJapanesePhoneticAnalyzerContract.winmd;,Windows.Management.Deployment.Preview.DeploymentPreviewContract.winmd;,Windows.Management.Workplace.WorkplaceSettingsContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.AppBroadcasting.AppBroadcastingContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.AppRecording.AppRecordingContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Capture.AppBroadcastContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Capture.AppCaptureMetadataContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Capture.GameBarContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Devices.CallControlContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.MediaControlContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Playlists.PlaylistsContract.winmd;,Windows.Media.Protection.ProtectionRenewalContract.winmd;,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.LegacyNetworkOperatorsContract.winmd;,Windows.Networking.XboxLive.XboxLiveSecureSocketsContract.winmd;,Windows.Perception.Automation.Core.PerceptionAutomationCoreContract.winmd;,Windows.Security.EnterpriseData.EnterpriseDataContract.winmd;,Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasContract.winmd;,Windows.Storage.Provider.CloudFilesContract.winmd;,Windows.System.Profile.ProfileRetailInfoContract.winmd;,Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileContract.winmd;,Windows.System.UserProfile.UserProfileLockScreenContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.ApplicationsSettingsContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics.AnimationMetricsContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowDialogsContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.Shell.SecurityAppManagerContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting.HostingContract.winmd;,Windows.Web.Http.Diagnostics.HttpDiagnosticsContract.winmd;,Windows.Embedded.DeviceLockdown.DeviceLockdownContract.winmd;,Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators.NetworkOperatorsFdnContract.winmd;,Windows.Phone.PhoneContract.winmd;,Windows.Phone.StartScreen.DualSimTileContract.winmd;,Windows.UI.WebUI.Core.WebUICommandBarContract.winmd".
Error: method `System.Boolean UnityEngine.Texture2D::Reinitialize(System.Int32,System.Int32,UnityEngine.TextureFormat,System.Boolean)` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Vuforia.Unity.Engine.dll at System.Void Vuforia.Image::ResizeTexture(UnityEngine.Texture2D,System.Int32,System.Int32,UnityEngine.TextureFormat).

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter () (at C:/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1194)
PostProcessWinRT:Process () (at C:/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:203)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

2.
Reference rewriter: Error: method `System.Boolean UnityEngine.Texture2D::Reinitialize(System.Int32,System.Int32,UnityEngine.TextureFormat,System.Boolean)` doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from Vuforia.Unity.Engine.dll at System.Void Vuforia.Image::ResizeTexture(UnityEngine.Texture2D,System.Int32,System.Int32,UnityEngine.TextureFormat).
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
PostProcessWinRT:RunReferenceRewriter () (at C:/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:1196)
PostProcessWinRT:Process () (at C:/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/Extensions/Managed/PostProcessWinRT.cs:203)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

換過不同版的vuforia engine，一樣會有錯誤

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, we can see that the error message is method does not exist. Such problems are caused by incompatible framework versions. The official recommendation is to use Unity 2021.3 LTS for the unity version, refer to [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version). For more information about using Vuforia Engine and Unity, please refer to [Using Vuforia with Unity - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/vuforia-development-overview)

Comment: 版本換到2021.3.10版，MRTK-Quest的Prefabs產生錯誤，像是Problem detected while importing the Prefab file: 'Packages/com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation/Providers/Oculus/XRSDK/MRTK-Quest/Prefabs/MRTK-Quest_LocalAvatar.prefab'.
The file might be corrupt or have missing nested Prefabs. See details below.
Errors:
 Prefab instance problem: MRTK-Quest_LocalAvatar (Missing Prefab with guid: 84c8b8609f9bb434eaf5248f17ff1293)